# Why is it when reading a spreadsheet it interprets some columns as having booleans?

Tags: r, readxl

When I read the spreadsheet in with
`DataTable <- read_excel("Final Shipping Data.xlsx") it interprets about 20 columns as booleans even though they were all designated numbers in excel.

[image: My Matrix in r]

[image: My spreadsheet in Excel]

Comment: If there are only 1 and 0s, they can be treated as TRUE FALSE. Please check your data and share sample for only those where you see this problem. You have given "CVO Asia" showing T/F but where is corresponding input data?

Comment: How many row are in the data?

Comment: There are 4019 rows, some are #N/A for about 1500

Comment: There were two many NA rows. So I think it defaulted those to Booleans, I changed my code to `DataTable <- read_excel("Final Shipping Data.xlsx", col_types = "numeric")`